# adding a dynamic css value in CGridView via htmlOptions

Tags: yii

Trying to add a dynamic class value to one of my columns in CGridView:

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'button-column $data->team'),
```

However the class just comes out as '$data->team' anyway to achieve this? Some sort of eval call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
'cssClassExpression'=>'$data->team',
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'button-column'),
```

**Edit:**(Just a little more explanation)

According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#cssClassExpression-detail) for `cssClassExpression` the following special variables are available:(Emphasis mine)

> the variable **$row** the row number (zero-based); **$data** the data model for the row; and **$this** the column object.

I would go so far as to say that whenever any special variables are not mentioned in the documentation, we can assume that most probably, we can't use them there (like in the case of `htmlOptions`).